# Shortest way to get the nth column of a line in BASH

Tags: bash, awk, cut

This works:

`echo column1 column2 |awk '{print $2}'`

This is one character shorter:

`echo column1 column2 |cut -d " " -f 1`

Are there shorter ways to do this?

Comment: You could define a custom command, e.g. a shell script in /usr/bin. If you use a 1-character script name, your command would be 1 character long. However I don't see the purpose of reducing the chars for this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code golf. Try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `bash` for a shell, arrays work well for this, and avoid forking external processes:

```
$ x="one two three"
$ y=(${x})                 # note - no quotes, so we split on spaces
$ echo ${y[1]}
two
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  echo column1 column2|grep -Eo '\S*$'
column2

kent$  echo column1 column2|awk '$0=$2'    
column2

kent$  echo column1 column2|sed 's/.* //'
column2
```

this assumes that the `echo ...` part was fixed..

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
awk '$0=$2'
```

Comment: Depends if the OP wants to print a blank line when there is no value in the 2nd column. This answer does not.

Answer (score 0):

`echo column2` would be briefest way to do this as it removes the need for a pipe and uses zero characters beyond the echo.